# org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Long out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm trying to deserialize this json:

```
{
"login": "tamtoum",
"lastName": "brahim",
"emailAddress": "brahim@aqqss.com",
"firstName": "sldmldm",
"userProfileId":  [
"profil1",
"profilmobile"
],
"organizationId":[
"oui",
"non"
]

}
```

Class java:

```
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NONE, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
 public class CreateUserDto { 
private String login;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String emailAddress;
private List<String> userProfileId;
private List<String> organizationId;

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
}
public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}
public List<String> getUserProfileId() {
    return userProfileId;
}
public void setUserProfileId(List<String> userProfileId) {
    this.userProfileId = userProfileId;
}
public List<String> getOrganizationId() {
    return organizationId;
}
public void setOrganizationId(List<String> organizationId) {
    this.organizationId = organizationId;
} 


}
```

Parser:

```
    public static <T> T parseRequest(String jsonRequest, Class<T> returnType) {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T requestJsonParsed = null;
    JsonNode jsonNode;  
    boolean hasError = false;

    try {   
        jsonNode = mapper.readValue(jsonRequest, JsonNode.class);
        requestJsonParsed = mapper.readValue(jsonNode, returnType); 
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        logger.error(REQ_ERR, e);
        hasError = true;
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        logger.error(REQ_ERR, e);
        hasError = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(REQ_ERR, e);
        hasError = true;
    } finally {
        if (hasError) {
            throw new JsonParsingException(REQ_ERR);
        }
    }

    return requestJsonParsed;
 }
```

I call this parser in this function:

```
       @RequestMapping(value = "/mobile/rest/create/user", method =     RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
    public CRUDResultDto createUser(@RequestBody String data) {
    CRUDResultDto crudResultDto = new CRUDResultDto();
    try {
        crudResultDto.setSuccess(false);
        CreateUserDto userRequestDto = JsonParserUtility.parseRequest(data, CreateUserDto.class);
        if (userRequestDto != null) {
            if (retrieveUserSA.findByLogin(userRequestDto.getLogin()) != null) {
                UserDto userDto = userDtoFactory.getInstance(userRequestDto);
                userDto.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(userDto.getPassword(), null));
                addUserSA.insert(userDto);
                crudResultDto.setSuccess(true);
            }
        }
    } catch (JsonParsingException e) {
        throw new FunctionalException(CommonError.BAD_JSON_REQUEST, null);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new TechnicalException();
    }
    return crudResultDto;
}
```

But i'm geeting this strange error
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Long out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.efsm.data.dto.user.UserRequestDto["userProfileId"])

any help would be appreciated

*********************EDIT*************************************

The error was stupid i din't use the correct class to parse

CreateUserDto userRequestDto = JsonParserUtility.parseRequest(data, CreateUserDto.class);

I used UserDo instead of CreateUserDto

Comment: how do you call your `parseRequest` method, may you show?

Comment: i edit my question ...

Answer (score 0):

The error was stupid i din't use the correct class to parse

CreateUserDto userRequestDto = JsonParserUtility.parseRequest(data, CreateUserDto.class);

I used UserDo instead of CreateUserDto